# How to show only subcategories in parent category not parent category?

Tags: php, posts, categories, custom-taxonomy, children

I just want to show only subcategories of specific parent category on parent category page.
I have 1 parent category `videos` and 3 child categories `art,funny,and technology` of that parent.

I didn't assigned my parent `videos` category to my child categories, but I made them child of that `videos` parent cateogry.

and I don't want to show parent categories on parent category page and neither want to show any category when go to any post related of child category page.

How to do this? any idea?

I am using this code. And I used this code into my category.php file.

```
   <?php
            if (is_category())
            {
            $cur_cat = get_query_var('cat');
            if ($cur_cat) 
               {
                $new_cats = wp_list_categories('echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_cat  .'&depth=1&title_li=&&show_count=1&hide_empty=0');

               }
            }
        ?>
```

But this is not working desired as I want.

I also tried 1 more solution for that,I made another template called `content-videos.php`
and I call that template with

```
   <?php if ( in_category('videos')):?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'videos' ); ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="block"><?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format()    ); ?></div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif;?>
```

in my `category.php` template. and I put my 1st code into `content-videos.php`.that solved my 1st problem, but my next problem was that when I go to in any subcategory page there is noting show except `No categories`

please suggest me any solution of this I am suffered too much to finding the right solution what I want.

Comment: That's just how categories work. If I have a box labelled junk, and inside it there's a box called 'blue junk', then the junk box contains all the blue junk too. Categories and hierarchical taxonomies work the same way.

Comment: Is this the answer of my question?

Comment: It's useful information, I'm not entirely sure what form your desired result would take, be it a list of child categories, or showing posts that are only in the current term and no others, the latter of which would have complexity issues

Comment: well its not my answer, I want complete answer with solution.

Comment: I think my point is, it isn't clear what a complete answer would give you, can you edit your question to be clearer about what you're trying to achieve? What is the expected output?

Comment: well well, so what I have so much described up there in my code and explanation?

If you concentrate on my question and read carefully then I dont think so  I have to explain more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12734/discussion-between-mr-beginner-and-tom-j-nowell)